# No data to display in Angularjs Fusion Charts

Tags: angularjs, fusioncharts

How do I add $scope.ok.rate value to myDataSource1 object in Angular Js? Chart is working normal when the data is string but if I set the value: $scope.ok.rate, I get the error: No data to display.

```
if (response.TotalPercent3) {
            $scope.ok = {
                "rate": response.TotalPercent3,
                "total": response.Total3
            };

console.log($scope.ok.rate); // Here I can see the output. It has a value.

    $scope.myDataSource1 = {
        chart: {caption: "Some week"},
        data: [
            {label: "Saturday", value: $scope.ok.rate},
            {label: "Sunday", value: "300"},
```

Comment: I don't know fusioncharts, but you could use .toString() `response.TotalPercent3.toString()`. My other guess is that you have Sunday's value as "300" instead of 300, and you can't have varying types for values.

Comment: I think the issue here is you are changing the $scope.ok outside the angular reach. So the digest cycle is not being triggered probably. I would be really keen to look to it if you provide a fiddle or a plunker link stating the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please once check the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654554/5102631. Let me know if it answers your question.